# Metodo de Login Visual Studio2017

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Buenas tengo un método para la comprobación de un login, el cual debe de validar tres veces los datos y al finalizar debe de cerrarse la aplicación. Lo estoy colocando en la opción del botón para que lleve el detalle

```
private void Verificar(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    //{
    //    int intentos = 0;
    //    try
    //    {
    //        if (txtUsuario.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
    //        {
    //            Usuarios u = new Usuarios();
    //            u.Nomusuario = txtUsuario.Text.Trim();

    //            List<Usuarios> lstusuarios = LN.ConsultarUsuarios(u);
    //            if (txtUsuario.Equals(u.Nomusuario) && txtpass.Equals(u.contrasena))
    //            {
    //                MessageBox.Show("Bienvenido al Sistema");
    //            }
    //            else
    //            {
    //                MessageBox.Show("Revise Usuario y contraseña", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    //                intentos++;

    //                if (intentos == 1)
    //                {
    //                    MessageBox.Show("Intenta de nuevo Primer Intento", "Fallaste!", 
    //         MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    //                    txtpass.Clear();
    //                    txtpass.Select();
    //                    intentos++;
    //                }
    //                else
    //                {
    //                    if (intentos == 2)
    //                    {
    //                        MessageBox.Show("Intenta de nuevo Segundo Intento", "Fallaste!",
    //                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    //                        txtpass.Clear();
    //                        txtpass.Select();
    //                        intentos++;
    //                    }
    //                    if (intentos == 3)
    //                    {
    //                        MessageBox.Show("Se ha introducido la contraseña incorrecta 3 veces! \n\nEste programa se cerrara!",
"Aviso!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    //                        Application.Exit();
    //                    }
    //                }
    //            }
    //        }
    //        else
    //        {
    //            MessageBox.Show("Debe indicar usuario", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    //            txtUsuario.Focus();
    //        }
    //    }
    //    catch (Exception ex)
    //    {

    //        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    //    } '''
```

El problema al ejecutar el código es que cuando entra no valida y cae de una vez en la opción de no funciona.

Comment: Que seria que caiga? lanza excepcion? debugeaste y te fijaste donde no hace el chequeo?

Comment: Buenas, se hace un loop nada mas y no termina ni valida el usurio

Comment: tenes la validación sobre un Evento y cada vez que moves el mouse se ejecuta. por eso es el loop, deberia colocarlo sobre el evento click del boton y acortaria bastante a tu metodo

Comment: pudiste corregir?

Comment: Buenas, si el problema lo tenia en donde y como ubique al contador, tuve que reestructurarlo todo de nuevo y lo consegui Gracias por la asistencia

Answer (score 1):

El error parece ser el evento que estás utilizando. El código que has puesto deberías meterlo en el evento click del botón.

Comment: Si en efecto, realice los cambios y mofique un poco el codigo y dio el resultado esperado